# how to run this code in django template 

Tags: python, django, templates

this is my code :

```
{% for i,j in enumerate(a) %}
    {{i}} ,{{j}}
{% endfor%}
```

but , it show a error , i think it cant run the `enumerate` method ,

so how to run the `enumerate`  in django template ,

thanks

Answer (score 122, accepted):

The template subsystem has some special constructs built into the for/endfor block that allows you to access the current index of the loop without having to call `enumerate`.

```
{% for j in a %}
    {{ forloop.counter0 }}, {{ j }}
{% endfor %}
```

While this snippet solves your immediate problem, if you're expecting to have access to Python builtins and other Python constructs inside your Django templates, you may be misunderstanding the sandbox that it provides/enforces.

Comment: Also, for everyone's quick reference: `forloop.counter0` refers to 0-indexed counter while `forloop.counter` refers to 1-indexed counter

Answer (score 18):

you can use `{{ forloop.counter }}` or `{{ forloop.counter0 }}` for the same effect, the latter is 0-indexed, thus more like `enumerate`.

Answer (score 10):

```
{% for item in a %}
    {{ forloop.counter }}, {{ item }}
{% endfor %}
```

[Link related](http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter04/)

Answer (score 8):

Django template makes up the presentation layer and are not meant for logic. From the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/templates/)

> If you have a background in programming, or if you’re used to languages which mix programming code directly into HTML, you’ll want to bear in mind that the Django template system is not simply Python embedded into HTML. This is by design: the template system is meant to express presentation, not program logic.

Now to get the same functionality in Django, you will have to complete your logic in the views.
views.py

```
def my_view(request, ...):
    ....
    enumerated_a = enumerate(a);
    ....
    return render_to_response('my_template.html', {'enumerated_a ': enumerated_a }..)
```

Now `enumerate` function returns an enumerate object which is iterable.
my_template.html

```
{% for index, item in enumerated_a %}
    {{ index }},{{ item }}
{% endfor %}
```

Although I think you can probably change it to an enumerated list and use it like that as well.

Comment: I kinda liked this idea at first glance, but when I tried to use this on a `formset` it failed - giving Error with Management form. This could be probably overcome by more tweaking.

Comment: The issue was with your management form, not enumerate.

Answer (score 1):

If however you need to use a function within a template, i suggest you create a filter or a tag instead. For reference, check out http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/howto/custom-template-tags/