# Indexing a QuerySet array in django templates

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-queryset

I'm trying to access a queryset array that I passed from the views in the templates. I want to index each entry using a numeric iterator. I'm using a django snippet to get the range of customers. Here is what I have done so far:

```
{% for cust in customer_comments %}
    {% for i in cust|length|get_range %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{cust.i.customer_id}}</td>
        <td>{{cust.i.feedback_detail}}</td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}                                                    
{% endfor %}
```

When I iterate using `cust.i.customer_id` it displays nothing. But when I use `cust.0.customer_id` or `cust.1.customer_id`, it displays what I want it to. Kindly help why i is not working.

Btw this is how I initialized the `customer_comments` object in views.

```
customer_comments = []
for i in all_features:
   if OpenFeedback.objects.filter(feature_id = i.feature_id).exists(): 
      feedback_obj = OpenFeedback.objects.filter(feature_id = i.feature_id)
      customer_comments.append(feedback_obj)
```

Comment: Why not simply iterating over the `cust` list without indexing it? The `cust.i` would be replaced by the loop variable.

Comment: you mean like cust.customer_id? Even if I do this nothing displays. I just don't seem to understand why cust.0.customer_id works and cust.i.customer_id does not.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to run this code in django template](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5013367/how-to-run-this-code-in-django-template)

Comment: @user590028 so should I go like this for indexing? cust.forloop.counter0.customer_id
please tell me the exact syntax, I'm a beginner at Django

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't iterate like that in Python or in Django templates: you iterate through the list itself.

```
{% for customer in cust %}
<tr>
    <td>{{customer.customer_id}}</td>
    <td>{{customer.feedback_detail}}</td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I can't believe what I was doing. That was so simple. Thank you so much!