# Django - get element index in a list in template

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I have a list in template for iteration, and when iterating, I want to print its index in this list. Now I am using `list.index(element)`, but this does not work.

I do:

```
<tbody>
   {% for core in cores %}
   <tr>
       <td>{{cores.index(core)}}</td>     <!-- this line doesn't work -->
       <td>{{core.user}}</td>             <!-- this line works. -->
```

This is not the way? I have to do `for i in length(cores)`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5013367/how-to-run-this-code-in-django-template

Comment: Quickest and exactly what I want... Give it as an answer and I accept it.

Comment: The link has a bad title.... I suggest mark it as duplicate of this question or an edit.. I searched beforehand and apparently the title was misleading although the answers are valuable..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`{{forloop.counter}}` this is it.
Only add this line before the element

Comment: Yes I see it in the first comment... however I think counter and counter0 should all be mentioned... thanks.

Comment: How to use it in array and list? cores[forloop.counter]