# How to iterate 3 nested lists on django template

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

I have 3 lists on my views and I want to iterate it with django
template with nestedly.
Eg: here I have 3 lists name card_postings,arrays and post_content

```
 card_postings = ['Indicatif', 'Subjonctif', 'Conditionnel',
    'Participe', 'Impératif', 'Infinitif']

    arrays = [['Présent', 'Imparfait', 'Futur', 'Passé simple', 'Passé
    composé', 'Plus-que-parfait', 'Passé antérieur', 'Futur antérieur'],
    ['Présent', 'Imparfait', 'Plus-que-parfait', 'Passé'], ['Présent',
    'Passé première forme', 'Passé deuxième forme'], ['Présent', 'Passé
    composé', 'Passé'], ['Présent', 'Passé'], ['Présent', 'Passé']]

    post_content = [["j'ai", 'tu as', 'il/elle a', 'nous avons', 'vous
    avez', 'ils/elles ont'], ["j'avais", 'tu avais', 'il/elle avait', 'nous
    avions', 'vous aviez', 'ils/elles avaient'], ["j'aurai", 'tu auras',
    'il/elle aura', 'nous aurons', 'vous aurez', 'ils/elles auront'],
    ["j'eus", 'tu eus', 'il/elle eut', 'nous eûmes', 'vous eûtes',
    'ils/elles eurent'], ["j'ai eu", 'tu as eu', 'il/elle a eu', 'nous
    avons eu', 'vous avez eu', 'ils/elles ont eu'], ["j'avais eu", 'tu
    avais eu', 'il/elle avait eu', 'nous avions eu', 'vous aviez eu',
    'ils/elles avaient eu'], ["j'eus eu", 'tu eus eu', 'il/elle eut eu',
    'nous eûmes eu', 'vous eûtes eu', 'ils/elles eurent eu'], ["j'aurai
    eu", 'tu auras eu', 'il/elle aura eu', 'nous aurons eu', 'vous aurez
    eu', 'ils/elles auront eu'], ["que j'aie", 'que tu aies', "qu'il/elle
    ait", 'que nous ayons', 'que vous ayez', "qu'ils/elles aient"], ["que
    j'eusse", 'que tu eusses', "qu'il/elle eût", 'que nous eussions', 'que
    vous eussiez', "qu'ils/elles eussent"], ["que j'eusse eu", 'que tu
    eusses eu', "qu'il/elle eût eu", 'que nous eussions eu', 'que vous
    eussiez eu', "qu'ils/elles eussent eu"], ["que j'aie eu", 'que tu aies
    eu', "qu'il/elle ait eu", 'que nous ayons eu', 'que vous ayez eu',
    "qu'ils/elles aient eu"], ["j'aurais", 'tu aurais', 'il/elle aurait',
    'nous aurions', 'vous auriez', 'ils/elles auraient'], ["j'aurais eu",
    'tu aurais eu', 'il/elle aurait eu', 'nous aurions eu', 'vous auriez
    eu', 'ils/elles auraient eu'], ["j'eusse eu", 'tu eusses eu', 'il/elle
    eût eu', 'nous eussions eu', 'vous eussiez eu', 'ils/elles eussent
    eu'], ['ayant'], ['ayant eu'], ['masc.sg.: eu', 'masc.pl.: eus',
    'fém.sg.: eue', 'fém.pl.: eues'], ['aie', 'ayons', 'ayez'], ['aie eu',
    'ayons eu', 'ayez eu'], ['avoir'], ['avoir eu']]
```

Here each ‘card_postings’ has associated ‘arrays’, and each ‘arrays’
associated ‘post_content’.

picture of page [page structure what I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N2fPp.png)

And also I tried this with a zip list

> zipped_lists = zip(card_postings, arrays, post_content)

In my template is look like this

```
 {% for card,posts,contents in zipped_lists %}
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h4 class="text-center">{{ card }}</h4>
                    <div class="row row-cols-1 row-cols-sm-2 row-cols-md-3 g-3">
                      {% for post in posts %} 
                        <div class="col">
                        <div class="card">
                            <div class="card-header text-center text-primary">
                              <h5>{{ post }}</h5>
                            </div>
                            <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
                              <li class="list-group-item border-0">
                                {% for subj in contents %}
                                <i>{{subj}} <br> </i> 
                                {% endfor %}
                              </li>
                            </ul>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
      {% endfor %}
    </div>
```

Is there are any better way to do this thing please let me know I like your suggestions as well.there are similar questions such as here,here,here but any of these are not help my question.And also if you need more information please let me know

Comment: zipping and looping it runs for the shorter list and in your case card_posting is the short list.

Comment: as you stated, entries in lists are associated, I would suggest using relationships (one to one, one to many, many to one) to achieve.

Comment: @VimalanE I just scrape data from a website to views using beautifulsoup

Comment: @VimalanE can you show me the way with shorter list

Comment: I will write one answer based on my understanding if not solving do comment.

Comment: @VimalanE ok I really appreciate it

Comment: @VimalanE I know format is something like this `sorted(list, key=..., reverse=...)` but I don't know how to iterate it on django template.

Comment: I also have the kind a like same prob so did you find anything

Answer (score 0):

Considering the below example scenario to answer the above.
I have a topic called "Breaking News", "Latest News", which has sub topic called "From India", "From USA", and so on.
Each sub topic has many articles in it.
The tree structure for the above is

```
Times_of_India = {
Breaking News : 
{ 
"From India": [article1, article2, article3],
"From USA": [article1, article2, article3],
"From China": [article1, article2, article3]
}
Latest News:
{ 
"From India": [article1, article2, article3],
"From USA": [article1, article2, article3],
"From China": [article1, article2, article3]
}
}
}
```

and lets say for an instance I want to display breaking news on left side of the page and latest right of the page and under both news section just display news. To do this the approach would be as follows

```
for key, value in Times_of_India.items()
 <card>key</card>
   if isinstance(value, dict):
    for k, v in value.items():
      <posts>k</posts>
       if isinstance(v, list):
         for d in v:
           <li>d</li>
```

Explanation:
Breaking_news is your cards, Location is you arrays and articles list is your post content. The above code does not check for any association just displays whatever is there.
You can have a condition checks.

Note: I removed concept of three lists and made dictionaries which has key and value and I can use keys as my associations.

Hope this helps if not feel free to ask.

Comment: The problem is in my case those three lists name `card_postings, arrays, post_content` are not static they are dynamic.Which means they change every time when I run program

Comment: you get it as lists to django from web page ? meaning how you are getting those lists from front end ?

Comment: I can answer you better if I get to know how lists are associated. I cant see any associations between them.

Comment: Well this is the [website](https://conjugator.reverso.net/conjugation-french-verb-aller.html) I used to scrape data.In here take **INDICATIF** as `card_posttings` ,**Présent** as `arrays` and **je vais** as `post_content`.

Comment: so you getting it as lists to you django from scrape tool

Comment: I got to know what you are trying to achieve. I will re-write the above answer.

Comment: well How can i iterate in django template because I don't know how to use `isinstance` in django template.

Answer (score 0):

I have written a python code with the same example lists and it produces the following output as you are expecting without using isinstance. Have a look
Same logic can be implemented easily in django template as well.

```
card_postings = ['Indicatif', 'Subjonctif', 'Conditionnel',
    'Participe', 'Impératif', 'Infinitif']

arrays = [
    ['Présent', 'Imparfait', 'Futur', 'Passé simple', 'Passé composé', 'Plus-que-parfait', 'Passé antérieur', 'Futur antérieur'],
    ['Présent', 'Imparfait', 'Plus-que-parfait', 'Passé'],
    ['Présent','Passé première forme', 'Passé deuxième forme'],
    ['Présent', 'Passécomposé', 'Passé'],
    ['Présent', 'Passé'],
    ['Présent', 'Passé']
]

post_content = [
    ["j'ai", 'tu as', 'il/elle a', 'nous avons', 'vousavez', 'ils/elles ont'],
    ["j'avais", 'tu avais', 'il/elle avait', 'nousavions', 'vous aviez', 'ils/elles avaient'],
    ["j'aurai", 'tu auras','il/elle aura', 'nous aurons', 'vous aurez', 'ils/elles auront'],
    ["j'eus", 'tu eus', 'il/elle eut', 'nous eûmes', 'vous eûtes','ils/elles eurent'],
    ["j'ai eu", 'tu as eu', 'il/elle a eu', 'nousavons eu', 'vous avez eu', 'ils/elles ont eu'],
    ["j'avais eu", 'tuavais eu', 'il/elle avait eu', 'nous avions eu', 'vous aviez eu','ils/elles avaient eu'],
    ["j'eus eu", 'tu eus eu', 'il/elle eut eu','nous eûmes eu', 'vous eûtes eu', 'ils/elles eurent eu'],
    ["j'auraieu", 'tu auras eu', 'il/elle aura eu', 'nous aurons eu', 'vous aurezeu', 'ils/elles auront eu'],
    ["que j'aie", 'que tu aies', "qu'il/elleait", 'que nous ayons', 'que vous ayez', "qu'ils/elles aient"],
    ["quej'eusse", 'que tu eusses', "qu'il/elle eût", 'que nous eussions', 'quevous eussiez', "qu'ils/elles eussent"],
    ["que j'eusse eu", 'que tueusses eu', "qu'il/elle eût eu", 'que nous eussions eu', 'que vouseussiez eu', "qu'ils/elles eussent eu"],
    ["que j'aie eu", 'que tu aieseu', "qu'il/elle ait eu", 'que nous ayons eu', 'que vous ayez eu',"qu'ils/elles aient eu"],
    ["j'aurais", 'tu aurais', 'il/elle aurait','nous aurions', 'vous auriez', 'ils/elles auraient'],
    ["j'aurais eu",'tu aurais eu', 'il/elle aurait eu', 'nous aurions eu', 'vous auriezeu', 'ils/elles auraient eu'],
    ["j'eusse eu", 'tu eusses eu', 'il/elleeût eu', 'nous eussions eu', 'vous eussiez eu', 'ils/elles eussenteu'],
    ['ayant'],
    ['ayant eu'],
    ['masc.sg.: eu', 'masc.pl.: eus','fém.sg.: eue', 'fém.pl.: eues'],
    ['aie', 'ayons', 'ayez'],
    ['aie eu','ayons eu', 'ayez eu'],
    ['avoir'],
    ['avoir eu']
]

for index, card in enumerate(card_postings):
    print(card)
    for i, array in enumerate(arrays[index]):
        print("\t", array)
        print("\t\t", post_content[i])
    del post_content[0:len(arrays[index])]
```

The output is as follows:

```
Indicatif
     Présent
         ["j'ai", 'tu as', 'il/elle a', 'nous avons', 'vousavez', 'ils/elles ont']
     Imparfait
         ["j'avais", 'tu avais', 'il/elle avait', 'nousavions', 'vous aviez', 'ils/elles avaient']
     Futur
         ["j'aurai", 'tu auras', 'il/elle aura', 'nous aurons', 'vous aurez', 'ils/elles auront']
     Passé simple
         ["j'eus", 'tu eus', 'il/elle eut', 'nous eûmes', 'vous eûtes', 'ils/elles eurent']
     Passé composé
         ["j'ai eu", 'tu as eu', 'il/elle a eu', 'nousavons eu', 'vous avez eu', 'ils/elles ont eu']
     Plus-que-parfait
         ["j'avais eu", 'tuavais eu', 'il/elle avait eu', 'nous avions eu', 'vous aviez eu', 'ils/elles avaient eu']
     Passé antérieur
         ["j'eus eu", 'tu eus eu', 'il/elle eut eu', 'nous eûmes eu', 'vous eûtes eu', 'ils/elles eurent eu']
     Futur antérieur
         ["j'auraieu", 'tu auras eu', 'il/elle aura eu', 'nous aurons eu', 'vous aurezeu', 'ils/elles auront eu']
Subjonctif
     Présent
         ["que j'aie", 'que tu aies', "qu'il/elleait", 'que nous ayons', 'que vous ayez', "qu'ils/elles aient"]
     Imparfait
         ["quej'eusse", 'que tu eusses', "qu'il/elle eût", 'que nous eussions', 'quevous eussiez', "qu'ils/elles eussent"]
     Plus-que-parfait
         ["que j'eusse eu", 'que tueusses eu', "qu'il/elle eût eu", 'que nous eussions eu', 'que vouseussiez eu', "qu'ils/elles eussent eu"]
     Passé
         ["que j'aie eu", 'que tu aieseu', "qu'il/elle ait eu", 'que nous ayons eu', 'que vous ayez eu', "qu'ils/elles aient eu"]
Conditionnel
     Présent
         ["j'aurais", 'tu aurais', 'il/elle aurait', 'nous aurions', 'vous auriez', 'ils/elles auraient']
     Passé première forme
         ["j'aurais eu", 'tu aurais eu', 'il/elle aurait eu', 'nous aurions eu', 'vous auriezeu', 'ils/elles auraient eu']
     Passé deuxième forme
         ["j'eusse eu", 'tu eusses eu', 'il/elleeût eu', 'nous eussions eu', 'vous eussiez eu', 'ils/elles eussenteu']
Participe
     Présent
         ['ayant']
     Passécomposé
         ['ayant eu']
     Passé
         ['masc.sg.: eu', 'masc.pl.: eus', 'fém.sg.: eue', 'fém.pl.: eues']
Impératif
     Présent
         ['aie', 'ayons', 'ayez']
     Passé
         ['aie eu', 'ayons eu', 'ayez eu']
Infinitif
     Présent
         ['avoir']
     Passé
         ['avoir eu']
```

Hope this helps. Feel free to ask if you dont understand.

Comment: Actually this answer is work with python but how Can I iterate things on django template.

Comment: yeah you can or another way to achieve is do in views and send only data to template

Comment: Yeah I can do it but thing is there is lot of things in template to iterate (divs in my template)

Comment: if that is the case simply iterate in template itself. Its just a loop logic which I have answered (enumerate) is used to loop with index. You can achieve without enumerate as well by having local index variable.

Comment: can you show it little bit in template

Comment: {% for item in a %}
    {{ forloop.counter }}, {{ item }}
{% endfor %}  where forloop.counter gives you the index

Comment: yeah I know that but when it come to this thing I can't use `{% for array in arrays[forloop.counter0] %} ` as second loop because it gives an error

Comment: could you please post the error ?

Comment: **Could not parse the remainder: '[forloop.counter0]' from 'arrays[forloop.counter0]**

Comment: I have to try out in django. use normal variable counter or index and increment it.

Comment: I can't use **enumerate** in django that's why I use `forloop.counter` .according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5013367/how-to-run-this-code-in-django-template) answer.

Comment: by the way do you need my source code

Comment: Do you zoom or google meetups